# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfe'

Tags: python, pickle

I have a pickle file `nr.pkl` that stored pre-trainned ML models. I need to Unpickle this file, I tried below code snippet to unpickle.

```
with open("nr.pkl", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

But it throws an error:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfe'
```

Why this error was shown? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This is a very generic error, that doesn't give much of a hint as to what's wrong with the pickle file.  Some possibilities: file was written with mode "w" instead of "wb", file has been transferred in some way that modified line endings, file is actually compressed or encoded.  Maybe it was written from a more recent Python version (you have to explicitly choose a backward-compatible pickle protocol version in that case), but I think that produces a more specific error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to read the contents of the file?

You can try to use `.read()` like this:

```
data = pickle.load(f.read())
```

Comment: `pickle.loads()` is what you'd have to use if you had read the data from the file yourself - but it's pretty much impossible for this to work, if letting pickle read from the file itself fails.